# Docker muti-stage

Tags: kubernetes, dockerfile, docker-multi-stage-build

Is it possible to copy one stage of a multi-stage Dockerfile into another?

For various business reasons I have been instructed to use a multi-stage Dockerfile, but what I really need to do is combine the appserver image and webserver image. This is fine in docker-compose as you can reference each section - but I am not sure if this can be done over GCP and Kubernetes.

My Dockerfile code is below.

```
FROM php:7.1-fpm as appserver

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libpq-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_pgsql pgsql
RUN apt-get update && \
     apt-get install -y \
         zlib1g-dev \
         && docker-php-ext-install zip

COPY ./app /var/www/html

FROM nginx:stable-alpine as webserver
COPY ./app /var/www/html/
COPY vhost-prod.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure, what are you trying to achieve by your Dockerfile above.

- multistage build is not for the above purpose
- you cannot throw any problem at multi-stage build and solve it
- multi-stage build is to build the binaries/code and copy it to the final image so that you dont carry the dev tools into production

For your use case , please make two docker files , one for the app, and other for proxy/nginx , build them independently and run/scale them independently.

In case of static content serving from nginx , you just need to run nginx with volume mount of static content.

Comment: So basically the answer is no - you can't copy one image into another?

Comment: multi-stage builds are not for copying one use case into the other , its to copy the build artifacts of one build into the other , I see that you are trying to merge two applications into one

Comment: Great I thought as much, but had been specifically directed to use multi-stage build (even though the application is straight up PHP with no build dependencies) and wanted to check I wasn't getting the wrong end of the stick.

Comment: yes you need to have separate dockerfiles , build pipelines for each app  , and then in the deployment state you just need to connect them together

Comment: you can use multi-stage build in case you are building something and want to copy the build artifact into final image , so that you dont have the build tools in the production deployment image